# java circle inside a circle , how to know if two circles overlap

Tags: java, object, geometry

this is some code i wrote in java, it is a circle object class. i wrote methods i need two more methods and im struggeling with the first one is 
a method that contains (circle c) that returns true if the specified circle c is inside circle. and the second one is a method overlaps(circle c) that returns true if th especified circle c overlaps with this circle. all i need is how to make those two methods with the parameter being another circle object

this is my code

```
public class Circle
{
// instance variables - replace the example below with your own
private double radius;
private double centerX;
private double centerY;

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Circle
 */
public Circle()
{
  this.radius = 1;
  this.centerX = 0;
  this.centerY = 0;
}
/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Circle
 */
public Circle(double radius, double centerx, double centery)
{
  this.radius = radius;
  this.centerX = centerX;
  this.centerY = centerY;
}
 /**
 * Constructor for objects of class Circle
 */
public Circle(double pRadius)
{
     radius = pRadius;
}
/**
 * An example of a method - replace this comment with your own
 * 
 * @param  y   a sample parameter for a method
 * @return     the sum of x and y 
 */
public void setRadius(double pRadius)
{
    radius = pRadius;
}
/**
 * getRadius method will return the radius of the cricle
 * @param none 
 * @return radius of type double
 */
 public double getRadius()
{
    return radius ;
}
/**
 * getcenterX method will return the x coordinates of the circle
 * @param none 
 * @return centerx of type double
 */
 public double getCenterX()
{
    return centerX ;
}
/**
 * getcenterY method will return the y coordinates of the circle
 * @param none 
 * @return centery of type double
 */
 public double getCenterY()
{
    return centerY ;
}
/**
 * 
 */
   public double calcPerimeter()
{
    return 2*Math.PI*getRadius();
}
/**
 * 
 */
   public double calcArea()
{
    return Math.PI*Math.pow(getRadius(),2);
}
/**
 * 
 */
public double distance(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2)
{
    return ( Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x1-x2,2)+ Math.pow(y1-y2,2))) ;

}
/**
 * 
 */
public boolean contains(double x, double y)
{
    double dist = distance(x, y, centerX, centerY); // calculate the distance between the point(x,y) and center of the circle
    boolean flag = false;
    if ( dist < radius)
    {
        flag = true;

    }
    else if ( dist > radius)
    {
       flag = false ;
    }
    else 
    {
        System.out.println("The point is on the circle.");
    }
    return flag;
}

}
/**
 * 
 */
public String toString()
{
    String outString = "The radius of the circle is: " + getRadius() + "\nThe perimeter of the circle object is; " + calcPerimeter()+ "\nThe area of the circle is: " + calcArea() ;
    return outString;
}
```

}

Comment: One circle is inside each other if the distance between the centres is less than or equal to the absolute difference between the two radii. Two circles overlap if the distance between the two centres is less than the sum of the two radii. The distance between centres is simple to find using Pythagoras' theorem (x^2+y^2=z^2).

Comment: i know the rule to find it im looking for how to make a method with the input being an object, and then before i make my if statement im having trouble understanding how there are going to be two radiuses if there is only one object. my teacher said there is one circle object in  the method. if there is only one object then where do i get the second radius.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;

/**
 *
 * @author MT0
 */
public class Circle {
    private Point2D.Double center;
    private double radius;

    public Circle(
            final double x,
            final double y,
            final double r
    ){
      assert( r >= 0 );
      center = new Point2D.Double( x, y );
      radius = r;
    }

    public Point2D.Double getCenter(){
        return center;
    }

    public double getRadius(){
        return radius;
    }

    public Double distance( final Point2D.Double point ){
        if ( point == null )
            return null;
        return getCenter().distance( point );
    }

    public boolean contains( final Point2D.Double point ){
        if ( point == null )
            return false;
        return distance( point ) <= getRadius();
    }

    public boolean overlaps( final Circle c ){
        return distance( c.getCenter() ) <= getRadius() + c.getRadius();
    }

    public boolean contains( final Circle c ){
        if ( c == null )
            return false;
        return distance( c.getCenter() ) <= Math.abs( getRadius() - c.getRadius() );
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks this does it in a different way but i think i can figure out how to do it using this thanks

Comment: im going to write a test class and see if this works for the circle

Comment: why does it give me complation error when i use c1.contains() if i want to use the method